# View/Query Performance

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have created a view on a local server, that gets it's data from a linked server. On the linked I only have Read rights.

I am trying to improve the performance of my view, I tried to create the view WITH SCHEMABINDING, but are not allowed to use SCHEMABINDING on remote access. I tried reading up on Materialized Views, Yes I know it is a function in Oracle, but wanted to know if there is something similar in SQL server 2008 r2.

Any Ideas on how to increase the performance of my query?

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vw_CustomerServiceLevel]

AS
SELECT *
FROM [10.205.0.70].Freightware.dbo.CustomerServiceLevelReportEOF RF
INNER JOIN [10.205.0.70].Freightware.dbo.CustomerServiceLevelReportDetail RD 
  ON (RD.HeaderGUID=RF.HeaderGUID)
INNER JOIN [10.205.0.70].Freightware.dbo.CustomerServiceLevelReportHeader RH 
  ON (RH.HeaderGUID=RD.HeaderGUID)
LEFT JOIN SDBPHASE2DW.dbo.DimDate dd
  ON CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), RH.StartDate, 103) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), dd.FullDate, 103)
LEFT JOIN SDBPHASE2DW.dbo.DimDate dd2
  ON CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), RH.EndDate, 103) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), dd2.FullDate, 103)
```

[image: Execution Plan]

Comment: Can you show the query and execution plan?

Comment: Given the `SELECT *` and no aggregates, why are you using `GROUP BY`?

Comment: I remove unnecessary code, forgot to remove the group by

Comment: What are the datatypes of `CustomerServiceLevelReportHeader.StartDate`, `CustomerServiceLevelReportHeader.EndDate` and `DimDate.FullDate`?

Comment: @XCom69 - Unnecessary code? Over half of the cost of this query is in the processing of that GROUP BY clause (it's responsible for the Sort operation, 4th from the left, costing 55%)

Comment: Ok sorry, gave you incomplete data. I have updated my execution plan and query. there is just under 1000000 records, but just the select query alone takes more than 5 minutes to execute

Comment: New execution plan shows that 95% of query takes 'Remote Query'. This can be related to your network and to number of rows returned from the remote server. Do you really need that much rows to be returned?

Comment: @Alexander 95% of query is just an estimated cost. Actual network performance does not affect this.

Comment: FYI: There is a SQL equivalent of an Oracle materialised view called an Indexed View, but you need to be able to schema bind the view to index it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few things that you can do in order to optimize your code:

1. Do you need all returns columns?If not, select only the columns you
   need.
2. Do you need to convert the fields on which joins are made. It seems
   that they are the same, so you can remove the convert statements.
3. Do you need all the records?If not, just use a use defined function
   instead a view - it will be the same as your view, except you are
   able to pass to it some parameters that will cut the returned data.